# Do I need to disconnect an xcb_connection_t that I got from XGetXCBConnection?

Tags: c++, c, xlib, xcb

Here's an example I saw for some GLX code:

```
display = XOpenDisplay(0);
// ...
xcb_connection_t *connection = XGetXCBConnection(display);
// ...
XCloseDisplay(display);
```

I noticed that there was no `xcb_disconnect` in there. Is this correct? Also, is `connection` still valid after the display is closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`XCloseDisplay` seems to undo the creation of the display (hence destroying it), and since the XCB connection object is derived from the display, it would seem reasonable that the connection becomes invalidated once the display is closed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. It would be great if you had a citation to back it up though.

Comment: I found it: `XCloseDisplay` explicitly calls `xcb_disconnect`: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/src/ClDisplay.c at line 71

Comment: And `dpy->xcb->connection` is exactly what `XGetXCBConnection` returns: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/src/x11_xcb.c

Comment: I am getting a segfault when closing the connection after XGetXCBConnection() on the same display O_o